# Convert comma separated string/list into table/Matrix format using PDI

Tags: string, csv, matrix, pentaho, kettle

Using Pentaho data integration (Kettle), I read a long string from a text file:

a, 1, 2, b, 3, 4, c, 5, 6, ...

Is there any PDI/Kettle steps or method to split this string to become an n column table format like below (the column name can be define freely):

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 3 | 4 |
| c | 5 | 6 |

the above just a simplify example, my real case is having different separator character and the column number (n) is bigger. But I just want to get the main problem solve first.

Comment: How you define the row in table? Like, in your example, letter a, b, c  indicating new row. Is this what you mean?

Comment: And also do you supply separator character (a,b,c, .......n) separately in your process?

Comment: The table row is define by number of element (n). like above example is 3 column field in a row. so is counting n = 3 element for one row. not define by data value. the separator in above example is comma, if can be any separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a **[SOLUTION](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UJ5l73Udo_1HRC_ZH4lAEqylKUzd2G_G?usp=sharing)** for you. In my solution I have set N=3, But you can set as many as you want. Also, you require to input Column name in 'Row denormaliser' step if you want to set N =3/4/5/N.

Although , you can set column name dynamic (if you want) using 'Meta Data Injection' step easily.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, although is quite complex, but manage to do the work. i also had come out with an answer, which is first use 'javascript' and regexp to replace the n separator to another line separator. then use 'split field to rows' to split to rows by the line separator, finally use 'split field' to split the fields by the original separator.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand about "different separator character". If you have different separators on the same line, such as a comma and a semicolon, then this is a tricky task for the PDI process. Then you need to cast all delimiters to the same type first. For example, in Notepad ++, make a replacement. Notepad ++ does a good job with large CSV files.

Further in the PDI there is a standard separator component "Split Fields".

Comment: 'different separator character' is mean to be in different file/case. each case is actually have the same separator. sorry for making you confuse.